# Initialization of component properties in Angular 12?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-package-format

I'm converting a component library over to Angular 12, and the linting is giving me errors on annotated properties like this one that will be initialized by the annotation:

```
@ViewChild(MatSort, { static: false }) sort: MatSort;
```

The error is:

> (property) DataTableComponent.sort: MatSort
> Property 'sort' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.ts(2564)

I'm also getting other strange errors.  For example:

```
  dataSource: MatTableDataSource<any> = new MatTableDataSource([])
```

Generates the following error:

> Type 'MatTableDataSource' is not assignable to type 'MatTableDataSource'.
> Types of property 'sortingDataAccessor' are incompatible.
> Type '(data: never, sortHeaderId: string) => string | number' is not assignable to type '(data: any, sortHeaderId: string) => string | number'.
> Types of parameters 'data' and 'data' are incompatible.
> Type 'any' is not assignable to type 'never'.ts(2322)

Thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Angular 12 by default will enables strict mode in [TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#strict). The strict flag enables a wide range of type checking behavior like strictNullChecks,strictPropertyInitialization.

> We can prevent the type checker from throwing an error with Angular's
> non-null assertion operator, !

```
@ViewChild(MatSort, { static: false }) sort!: MatSort;
```

Since strickNullChecks are enabled, empty array are infered as never[] , so our MatTableDataSource return never[] instead any[]

```
MatTableDataSource<never>(initialData?: never[] | undefined): never[]
```

we can fix this by adding any to MatTableDataSource

```
dataSource: MatTableDataSource<any> = new MatTableDataSource<any>([])
```